# .htaccess Redirect not redirecting for domain alias

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have stumbled upon a unique problem.

Site - http://example.com

Blog - http://example.net

Now the blog(example.net) was moved to example.com/example_blog (for unknown reasons it was done using domain alias).

The following .htaccess was added to route http://example.net/page to http://example.com/example_blog/page

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/example_blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now here is the problem since example.net is an alias of example.com I am able to access

http://example.net/folder_and_file_from_example.com

I would expect http://example.net/folder_and_file_from_example.com to be redirected to http://example.com/example_blog/folder_and_file_from_example.com (which would show a 404 error)

I hope I explained it clearly enough. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with below changes which needs to be done in above code.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I think it could be a server thing.